# Rails force format in specific methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a jbuilder file to make a special json output for an object.

My routes has the resource added in as a collection block and going to the URL with .json at the end works fine. How do I force the json format in that method only? I know you can set `respond_to :json` in the controller overall but not for a single method. How do i do that?

Answer (score -2):

this `, :defaults => {:format => 'json'}` after the `get 'xxx'` in the `collection do` block does it

Comment: Is this excerpt sufficient to help another user? Can you please post more code in order to provide a context?